# Как данные из 1 ячейки разделить на 2 ячейки

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Имеется кривая база адресов в Excel. Там наименование улицы вместе с номером дома указаны в одной ячейке. Их нужно разделить, то есть в 1 столбце наименование улицы,  а во 2-ом столбце номер дома. Каким наиболее простым способом это можно сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инструмент *Текст по столбцам* разделит не на два столбца, а по количеству запятых в текте.

Если нужно разделить по первой запятой:

```
=ЛЕВБ(H2;ПОИСК(",";H2)-1)
=ПСТР(H2;ДЛСТР(I2)+3;99)
```

или для стиля ссылок *R1C1*

```
=ЛЕВБ(RC[-1];ПОИСК(",";RC[-1])-1)
=ПСТР(RC[-2];ДЛСТР(RC[-1])+3;99)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Через текст по столбцам, с разделителем запятой получилось.

Comment: Добавь формулу, чтобы и другим пригодилось.

Comment: Это не формула. Инструмент такой: меню *Данные-Текст_по_столбцам*